# Corda Build error - Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation']

Tags: gradle, corda

I'm testing corda on my local machine. I was able to build and run 3 node network for [CordaApp tutorial](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-tutorial). But, when I build the sample demos provided in corda [repo](https://github.com/corda/corda), my build has error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'corda-project'.
```

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation']
>     Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.

I've followed the steps described in https://docs.corda.net/running-the-demos.html

How can I get past the plugin error?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue we've encountered before. Are you building the demos on the master branch? If so, check out the M14 branch, where the demos are known to work (`git checkout release-M14`).

It's also worth checking your version of Java, which needs to be `8u131` or higher.